# The set of functions: $A^B=B^A$ then $A=B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

a)Let $A=\{0,1\}$ and $B=\{a,b,c\}$. Find $A^B$.

Answer: $A^B$ is a set of functions from $B$ to $A$. Then $A^B=\{(a,0), (a,1), (b,0), (b,1), (c,0), (c,1)\}$.

b) Assume $A^B=B^A$. Prove that $A=B$.

Proof: Assume $A^B=B^A$

Assume A=Ø and B≠Ø. Then $Ø^B=B^Ø$.

Let b∈B, and f∈$Ø^B$. Then f:B→Ø. Then f(b)∈Ø, a contradiction. Hence B=Ø.

Next, assume A≠Ø and B≠Ø.

Let a∈A and f:B→A such that f:B→a. Then a∈$B^A$. Thus a∈B. Therefore A⊆B.

Similarly, let b∈B and f:A→B such that f:A→b. Then b∈$A^B$. Hence b∈A. Therefore, B⊆A. 
Thus, A=B.

AM I DOING IT RIGHT?

Comment: Are you doing it right? Sorry, no. $A^B$ should have 8 elements, for instance; what you wrote is $A\times B$. Also the second part is wrong.

Comment: By the way, you should probably say $A^B$ is _the_ set of functions from $B$ to $A$ (meaning the set of _all_ such functions.) The phrase "_a_ set of functions from $B$ to $A$" could refer to any subset of $A^B$.

Comment: @egreg A^B = {∅, {(a,0)}, {(a,1)}, {(b,0)}, {(b,1)}, {(c,0)}, {(c,1)}, BxA} Is that right?

Comment: No, a function from $B$ to $A$ should be a set of ordered pairs, one for each element of $B$.  In this case it will be something like $\{(a,0),(b,1),(c,1)\}$  There are eight of them, corresponding to the eight ways to fill in the second elements of each pair.  Recall the definition of a function-it takes each element of the domain ($B$) to a unique element of the range ($A$), so it has to have the same number of pairs as there are elements in the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part :
a function from $B$ to $A$ is a **set** of **ordered pairs** $(x,y)$ with $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ such that every element of A is the first component of one and only one ordered pair.

For example : $\big\{ (a,0), (b,0), (c,1)\big\}$ is a function from $B$ to $A$.

Now, $A^B$ is the set of **all** functions from $B$ to $A$. So $A^B$ is the set whose elements are the following functions (sets of ordered pairs) :

$\big\{ (a,0), (b,0), (c,0)\big\}$,
$\big\{ (a,0), (b,1), (c,0)\big\}$,
$\big\{ (a,0), (b,0), (c,1)\big\}$,
$\big\{ (a,0), (b,1), (c,1)\big\}$,
$\big\{ (a,1), (b,0), (c,0)\big\}$,
$\big\{ (a,1), (b,1), (c,0)\big\}$,
$\big\{ (a,1), (b,0), (c,1)\big\}$,
$\big\{ (a,1), (b,1), (c,1)\big\}$

Answer (score 2):

Hints for the second part.

Prove first that if one of $A$ and $B$ is empty, then also the other one is.

Next, assume both sets are non empty. Fix an element $a_0$ of $A$; then the constant function $f\colon B\to A$ mapping all elements of $B$ to $a_0$ is also an element of $B^A$; thus…

---

After seeing the comment, here's my solution.

Suppose $A=\emptyset$. If $B\ne\emptyset$, then $A^B=\emptyset$; but $B^\emptyset$ contains the empty function, so $B^A\ne A^B$, a contradiction. Hence $B=\emptyset$. By symmetry, from $B=\emptyset$ we deduce $A=\emptyset$.

Therefore we can assume $A\ne\emptyset$ and $B\ne\emptyset$. Let $a\in A$ and consider the function $f_a\colon B\to A$ defined by $f_a(b)=a$ for all $b\in B$. Since the image $\{a\}$ of $f$ is a subset of $A$ and $f\in A^B=B^A$ we conclude that the image is also a subset of $B$. Therefore $a\in B$; since $a$ is arbitrary, $A\subseteq B$.

By symmetry, $B\subseteq A$.

Comment: I try to follow your outline and I got this. Are all of my steps correct?

Comment: I try to follow your outline and I got this. Are all of my steps correct? Proof: Assume A^B=B^A. Assume A=Ø and B≠Ø. Then Ø^B=B^Ø. Let b∈B, and f∈Ø^B. Then f:B→Ø. Then f(b)∈Ø, a contradiction. Hence B=Ø. Next, assume A≠Ø and B≠Ø. Let a∈A and f:B→A such that f:B→a. Then a∈B^A. Thus a∈B. Therefore A⊆B. Similarly, let b∈B and f:A→B such that f:A→b. Then b∈A^B. Hence b∈A. Therefore, B⊆A. Thus, A=B.

Comment: @NadiaC I'd say it better, but it's basically correct.